# Pushing links along nav using affix in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How could I push my `<li>` elements along the nav container with a Bootstrap affix?

Here is an example of what I am trying to create:

http://www.autotrader.co.uk/

As you can see when you scroll down the page a JS event activates and the link elements slide along and a home button fades in. If you view this link:

http://www.dealerbyte.co.uk

You can see I have recreated the navbar however I am struggling create that pushing effect that Autotrader manages. I am using bootstrap and thought maybe an affix could achieve this but I'm not sure how to approach this?

Any tips would be awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use "sticky-header". which will provide functionality to do the same.